# Dockerized laravel + apache app 404 on static files

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting 404 on static file while accessing site.

Everything works perfectly except for one thing. Everything related to assets like css and js are not loaded (404).

Is it anything related to permission? or am I doing anything wrong in .htaccess?

**Folder structure**

```
.
├── app
├── artisan
├── bootstrap
├── bower_components
├── bower.json
├── changes.log
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
├── container
├── database
├── datafor.envfile.blade.php
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── Documentation
├── error_log
├── gulpfile.js
├── index_test.php
├── package.json
├── phpunit.xml
├── prod.env
├── public
├── README.md
├── resources
├── routes
├── run
├── storage
├── tests
├── Themes
└── vendor

14 directories, 16 files
```

***Docker file***

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

# 1. Install development packages and clean up apt cache.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    g++ \
    git \
    libbz2-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    zip \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 2. Apache configs + document root.
RUN echo "ServerName laravel-app.local" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# 3. mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# 4. start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    bz2 \
    calendar \
    iconv \
    intl \
    mbstring \
    opcache \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip

# 5. composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

COPY . /var/www/html
# RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install && php artisan key:generate

# 6. we need a user with the same UID/GID with host user
# so when we execute CLI commands, all the host file's ownership remains intact
# otherwise command from inside container will create root-owned files and directories
ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  laravel-app:
    build:
      context: '.'
      args:
        uid: ${UID}
    container_name: laravel-app
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#${UID}
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#${UID}
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - laravel-app

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db
    volumes:
      - ./run/var:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./run/dump/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=securerootpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - db

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend-network
```

***.htaccess***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    
# Disable index view
Options -Indexes

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

***Logs***

```
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /Themes/themeone/assets/site/js/testimonies/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 489 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /Themes/themeone/assets/site/js/testimonies/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 489 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/settings/UA9om04LXF1bxJL.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /Themes/themeone/assets/site/css/testimonies/owl.carousel.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/settings/2ap5AcV0XiEfsz1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/exams/categories/19-examimage.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/exams/categories/16-examimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/exams/categories/20-examimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/exams/categories/21-examimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
laravel-app    | 192.168.224.1 - - [28/Jun/2020:13:14:57 +0000] "GET /public/uploads/exams/categories/22-examimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1718 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home"
```

Comment: Have you configured Apache?

Comment: No didn't can you help me out on that?

Comment: You actually did it on `2.` and `3.` section of `Dockerfile`! Do you have a public folder inside public folder of your project?

Comment: No it's a single folder. FYI if you notice the logs some static files are from Themes folder  yet the public folder files are not working.

Comment: Another mistake I did I think I copied my code folder at STEP 11. So on step 2,3 there won't be a public folder. Changed the order but still didn't work.

Comment: No, I mean the url is incorrect `/public/uploads/...` shouldn't have `/public` prefix.
How did you build image? manually or with docker-compose?

Comment: Yes using docker-compose.yml up --build

Comment: Try with `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.